# MFC or .NET for migrating from Borland C++ (Builder)

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, mfc, vcl, borland-c++

I'm currently working on a small project, refurbishing and potentially implementing new features for a software created  sometime in 2008 in Borland C++ Builder. The software is obviously full of the Borland or VCL specific classes and to edit it I would need Borland C++.

Due to company regulations it seems that I may not be able to get hold of Borland C++ Builder, therefore I would need to recreate the whole program in Visual Studio, which I have access to (VS2010). Planning the project I thought this would be a sensible thing to do anyway, considering Borland's history.

Now here's where it gets tricky: I have very little OOP experience and have barely started learning C++ and Visual C++. The program itself is only a few hundred lines and I feel that I am capable of learning the language to an extent that I can tweak the code and potentially add a few new things to it within a reasonable time frame (I have about 8 weeks to finish this). Over the past few days I have read through the code and understood most of it (including how the Borland specific things worked), in addition to learning enough about C++ to work at this stage. However, I am now lost trying to decide how to proceed, whether I should start working with Windows Forms, use MFC or do something completely different.

From what I understand, the .NET framework works best with C#, but I think it's nearly impossible for me to learn C# parallel to C++ now and also learn it to an extent that I can migrate a program from the latter to the former. If possible, I would like to keep as much of the current code, as possible.

I also think that if I work with Windows Forms and .NET (even if I use C++/CLI instead of C#), not having a native end result could be an issue for the company. The whole program is only a few MB, having to install the .NET bundle would be silly and potentially problematic. However, I am a bit concerned that MFC would be complex and very different to Borland C++ VCL classes and I may struggle to understand it, while the Windows Forms building process is fairly straightforward. At the moment I am reading Ivor Horton's Beginning Visual C++ 2010, but I haven't yet found an answer from it or from other posts here.

**Considering the above:**

1. What would be best now, should I start working with Windows Forms and create something fast with C++/CLI or should I use MFC?
2. Out of these two, which would be easier to learn and use with the limited knowledge I have?
3. Which one of the two would enable me to keep most of the original code?
4. Would there be any point to try to learn C# as well?
5. Is there any other advice you could give related to my problem?

Comment: [Teach Yourself Programming in Ten Years](http://norvig.com/21-days.html). If you want to have the least little chance of success, don't try to learn any framework in addition to C++. Simply go with plain Windows API programming, and C/C++.

Comment: I wish I would have started learning any sort of OOP, C++ specifically, or anything else ten years ago. This sadly isn't case, and it doesn't change the fact that I have to work on this project now. Working in plain Windows API would mean having to learn that language as well, wouldn't it? I don't see how is that better than using a framework, which allows simpler building through VS2010.

Comment: The Windows API is exposed through a flat C interface (plus COM). There is no *language* to learn, in addition to C/C++. Windows API programming easier to learn than a framework for two reasons: `1` Generally good documentation. `2` A lot less invisible code paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Disclaimer: this is not the final and complete answer to the question, it was just too long to put in the comments, it is as good and precise as the question made (that is really not that much, obviously due maybe to some restrictions that the OP might have about the disclosure of the infos)**
without knowing what the other program does we can't do really much, but nowadays you can do anything with any programming language. I would presonally choose to go the c#.net road, because it's just much easier to work with c# than with c++ and nowadays any windows computer network will have .net framework installed in its machines, .net will also help you go easier to the web and to windows mobiles. But if you go the mfc c++ road you will surely not be left behind because anyway it is a "good" framework. both of these choices will restrict you to windows, just so you know.

1. MFC c++
2. MFC c++
3. don't know
4. yes, c#.net is easy to learn if you just want to do easy stuff
5. a few hundred lines program should really not scare you, so any road you choose will end up well, you might get stuck on the interface part and so c#.net will help very much with this, the other functionalities will pretty much have to be translated to new code anyway

Comment: What's the difference between `MFC c++` and `MFC`?

Comment: it's just the string that I normally use to search on google =) that's why I always add "c++" to MFC

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. The software does some preprocessing for a modelling tool, working with large arrays consisting of model coordinates and some other properties. It also has a primitive viewer built in. I know you can't become a developer overnight... I mostly understand what it does by now and grasp the level of C++ programming involved but was lost deciding what to do next. My problem with pure Windows API is that it seems far more laborious for this task (having to write everything directly rather than using the simpler drag&drop approach of building with MFC in VS2010).

Comment: Ok, that doesn't make a whole lot of sense. Maybe you haven't been keeping up with recent developments, but C# is hardly Windows-only. Besides the [Mono Project](http://www.mono-project.com/), there is [Xamarin](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/features/xamarin-vs.aspx) (now shipping directly with Visual Studio). The latter is the only option, if you want to target Windows, iOS, and Android from a single, shared codebase. This is essentially the **opposite** of Windows-only.

Comment: @laika: Drag&Drop, and a visual resource editor in general are only simple, if you know what they are doing. You only know that, if you know the Windows API. If you don't, you **will** (most definitely and inevitably) stumble, usually over the most tiniest problems. You will have to know what's behind the invisibility, or your MFC endeavor will be a failure.

Comment: This is an internal tool which only has to run on Windows.

Comment: @IInspectable I know it is inevitable that I will stumble. However, correct me if I'm wrong here, it seems to me from examples that I have seen on MSDN, books and elsewhere, that it is still less time consuming to trip up on issues with MFC and correct them as I go along than to learn how to work with Windows API from scratch.

Comment: @laika: Yes, sample code is deluding. It all makes sense, until you write your own code. You will get pretty far, pretty quickly. But when a problem hits you, you will have to learn the Windows API to diagnose your MFC issue. And now you have two problems. Maybe you are smarter than me. But when I started MFC (with a solid C++ background) I failed time upon time. If it weren't for a co-worker with a strong Windows API background, I wouldn't have finished a **single** project. Coincidentally, that co-worker didn't even know MFC, but had no difficulty using it at all, due to his background.

Comment: @IInspectable he doesn't need to become a pro in MFC, he just needs to translate a, what seems to be, small program. Surely there might be some not optimized code at the end of the project but it was his company who told him to do it and he just gotta do it with what he has. It's gonna be hard no matter which way he chooses, so there is no right answer to his question.